# Non Commutative function in mathematica

Tags: functions

How to define non-commutative functions in Mathematica? I am using the NCAlgebra package in Mathematica. I am having some trouble with the series expansions of those functions.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide an example of what you’re trying to do?